# lvm recovery with raid reconfiguration

Tags: raid, data-recovery, lvm

I have a Dell R510 with a H200 controller previously and I have two disks: a 2T SAS and a 250G SSD. I created two raid0s using those two disks on H200 and then created lvm on top of it. Here is my procedures:

1. created a vg-data using entire raid0 of the 2T SAS disk.
2. created a primary partition on raid0 of the 250G SSD and a logical partition with an extended partition.
3. created another vg-root using partition1 and partition5 of the SSD.
4. created a lv-swap and a lv-root in vg-root and lv-data in vg-data.
   installed Debian on lv-root.

Today, I decided to replace H200 with H700 because I got several free disks and I want to create a larger vg-data. However, I dramatically forgot to import previous raid configuration onto H700, but created new raids instead. So I got a raid0 for 2T SAS, a raid0 for 250G SSD, and a raid5 for xT. I then happily set boot device to the SSD raid0 and rebooted the server. After a long wait, I was dropped into grub-rescue mode saying couldn't find the lv-root.

I then downloaded a live CD and got a shell. When I used lvs to check lvs, I got warning message: device partition5 of the SSD has size of sector xxx which is smaller than corresponding pv size of xxx sectors. was device reduced?

I wonder, in this situation, is it still possible to recover all the lvs and data?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing nothing but replaced H710 with my old H200 and without changing anything, I got every bits back! Now I am backing up the whole system. I will reinstall H710 and restore system in future:) So my suggestions are:

```
don't panic
don't change anything yet
try old setting
backup routinely just in case.
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).